# DIV container height limited by browser window

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS and am having trouble getting my #wrapper DIV to expand to fit it's contents.
I've made sure that my containers all have 100% height, min-height didn't seem to do anything but I did try that also on both the #wrapper, html and body.  Is it something to do with relative vs. absolute positioning?  Here's an example of what i'm working on below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Updated 4.21.11 by owner)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CSS_Alpha_textArea</title>
<style type="text/css">
html {
    height: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1em;
    background-color: #gray;
    background-size: 100%;
    height:100%;
    clear: both;
}

#wrapper {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    /*background-color: #FFF;*/
    width: 75%;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}

.screen {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #3B6AA0;
    width: 75%;
    height:100%;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    /* CSS3 standard*/
    opacity:0.20;
    z-index: -100;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12%;
    right: 12%;
    clear: both;
}

.overlay {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 75%;
    height:100%;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12%;
    right: 12%;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: both;
}

#textArea {
    height: auto;
    width: 75%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    color: #FFF;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="screen"></div>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div id="textArea">
            <p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br>
            <p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br><p>textArea</p><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your code in the question rather than including a link that no one can view.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I tested it but it's obviously not working.

Comment: format your code by selecting it and then clicking on the little `{}` button..

Comment: Gaby thanks, for the tip. I edited my original post to make more sense, and then formatted it per your suggestion.  Much better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a container div, it is generally better to leave off the height property (unless you want to limit it for a specific reason). That will allow the height to expand as needed.

Comment: I tried that but it ended up breaking the .screen class, should I edit that class also?

Comment: I see. Is it possible to get a snippet of our HTML markup also? That might help.

Comment: Donnie I tried to upload my html but am having difficulties due to being new... Here's a link to a screenshot of what i'm seeing, not ideal but more helpful than not.  
-> http://i.imgur.com/Dd74i.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really able to tell much from the screeny, but your issue is most likely with the absolute positioning of the #wrapper and its child elements. You may not actually need to use positioning in this case, but I can't say that for sure since I'm flying blind.

Comment: Donnie I had to strip the navigation list and image refereence but below is the basic structure of the page:  Hope it helps.

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<div class="screen"></div>
<div class="overlay">
<h1 align="right" class="largeH1"> <strong>Test</strong></h1>
<div id="mainImage">
<div id="mainNav">
 <ul id="nav">
 </ul>
</div>

<img src=""/>
</div><br />

<div id="textArea">


</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

Comment: I think it might solve your problem to remove the absolute position from most of your elements so that things flow more naturally. I'm assuming you want .overlay to cover the entire page? If so, you may need to make that a direct child of <body> instead of #wrapper, so that you can position it without affecting the flow of the rest of the page.

Comment: Donnie, thanks for the reply.  I'll give it a try and respond here for future readers.. :)

Comment: Donnie, I updated the original post by consolidating everything into one file... This is much clearer as it shows how the textArea is overflowing all of it's parent containers.  You're right also in that i'd like to have a screen that runs the height of the page top-bottom no margins.  While having the textArea remain within it and unscreened.

Comment: I excluded some of your tags for brevity, but this should accomplish what you're after:

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#FFF;
 background-color: #gray;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 75%;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

.screen {
    width: 75%;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

.overlay {
    width: 75%;
 background-color: #727c86;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

#textArea {
    width: 75%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 color: white;
}

Comment: Cool, that looks much closer to what i'm after i'll have to play with the transparent effect a little but something in there fixed it, time to study now :) Donnie thanks a bunch for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

the 100% property means that it's going to fit on the parent's body.

check this out 
http://cssbeauty.com/skillshare/discussion/30/100-width-and-height/

Comment: as your screen width is 75%, any content in it that has 100% will fit the 75% of the screen parent's

Comment: So, I assumed that if the parent has 100% height then any child objects will have 100% height also regardless of the width.  Is that an incorrect assumption?

Comment: it is. Let me explain myself better: if a parent div has width:75%, it means that it occupies 75% of his parent's width. If a child div has width:100%, it width will be of 100% of the parent, that is the same as 75% of the parent's parent

Comment: basicly, it depends on where is your object positioned, what they parents are and their size

Comment: (this if you are using percentage)

Comment: I believe that my link is working again.  If it does then that shows how the text is overflowing it's container in the height direction only.  That's what's got me perplexed at the moment.

Comment: hmmm.  okay well here's a link to a screenshot, not ideal but at least it describes what i'm seeing.  Eric, thanks for your help BTW.
http://i.imgur.com/Dd74i.jpg

Comment: nvm that's what we are here for!

Comment: Eric does that image show better how things are overflowing their container?

Answer (score 0):

Your link is down, but it looks like if you add `overflow:hidden;` to your `#wrapper`, you'll get the desired effect.

Just keep in mind that absolute positioning removes the element from the natural flow of the document, so you'll need to consider how each item's content may overflow its container.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seems to actually expand the div it just hides what overflows...